# Django tells me the table is empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hello I have a problem using Django. Basically, I have a table by the name of `myTable` which has 65 entries. But the problem is in my `views.py` I do this :

`from MyProject.models import myTable`

and then in a function I do this :

```
myTable.objects.all()
```

and using the debugger I got this for `myTable.objects.all()` :

```
<QuerySet []>
```

So I don't understand at all because my table is not empty. Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Your table *is* empty. Are you looking in the right db?

Comment: It is strange because for django the table exists but when I go to Database in Pycharm I see the 65 entries.

Comment: Is pycharm looking at the same database? check your settings for both.

Comment: I think yes because I have only one table by the name of myTable

Comment: check your table name. It must be in the format `appname_modelname` ie `myproject_mytable`

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong table.

if you created your table with ORM, by default table name must be

```
myproject_mytable
```

if you have another existing table or you want to use another table name for a model you can add meta class to your model like this

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'myTable'
```

then django uses this table name for your model.